# Accessing Azure Service Fabric application not working

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I created a sample Stateless Web API Service Fabric Application and tested in local. I also created a Fabric cluster from Azure portal and deployed this application into cloud.

The endpoint of the cluster is - http://somename.westus.cloudapp.azure.com. When I am accessing the application with the endpoint specified in the ServiceManifest.xml, I am not getting response. I see timeout from the request trying for long time.

The url I tried is - http://somename.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:8901/api/values. 8901 is the endpoint defined in the ServiceManifest.xml.

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Many Thanks, Thirumalai M

Comment: It is likely that the ports and probes on the load balancer haven't been configured for that port, take a look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services/

Comment: Thanks jimpaine. The issue was the custom port was not configured while creating cluster. I was added the port, not it started working fine. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As jimpaine suggested, the below url given solution for configuring prob port number from client.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services/

I added the port 8901 in the prob, and the service started working.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ensure that the custom endpoint 8901 is enabled when you create your service fabric cluster in the portal, as described here
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-portal/#create-cluster-in-the-azure-portal